# Create dummies by matching characters

Tags: r, database, matching, dummy-variable

I'm quite new with R. Suppose you have the following dataset:

```
df=data.frame(year=rep(2000:2004,4),country=c(rep("Argentina",5),rep("Canada",5),
rep("Mexico",5),rep("USA",5)))
```

Then, let's say I have the following character vectors:

```
latin_america=c("Argentina","Mexico")
north_america=c("USA","Canada")
```

By using these 2 vectors, I want to create 2 new columns, i.e., latin and north, where latin takes value 1 if country equals either Mexico or Argentina, and zero otherwise.
North equals 1 if country equals either USA or Canada, and zero otherwise.

That's my attempt:

```
df$latin=0
df$north=0

df$latin[df$country==latin_america]=1
df$north[df$country==north_america]=1
```

Comment: You need `%in%`, not `==` when making your comparisons.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. Feel free to write the answer so that I can vote

Comment: Happy to have helped.  Your question is a duplicate, so I won't post an answer. Less clutter that way! :-)